# Decode string or int value in structure will return string("1") in Swift 4

Tags: swift, decode, decodable

I have a structure that some of the values will get Integer or string so I used this structure in my structure to parse JSON in the correct way but the problem is that when I want to print the value it will print string("1") instead of 1.

```
 public struct  player1_result_sheet : Decodable {
    let ans_1 : QuantumValue?
    let ans_2 : QuantumValue?
    let ans_3 : QuantumValue?
    let ans_4 : QuantumValue?
}
 enum QuantumValue: Decodable {

    case int(Int), string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let int = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Int.self) {
            self = .int(int)
            return
        }
        if let string = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(string)
            return
        }
        throw QuantumError.missingValue
    }
    enum QuantumError:Error {
        case missingValue
    }
}
```

Here is the printing after decode:

```
(self.res?.response?.detailData?[indexPath.row].player1_result_sheet?.ans_1!)!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the value without the enum wrapper, just implement `description`:

```
extension QuantumValue: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case let .string(string):
            return string
        case let .int(number):
            return "\(number)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that's worked without anything I just copy this extension in my codes !

Answer (score 1):

Your `enum` case is `string(String)` so it prints `case(value)`

> string("1")

You can solve it by creating varible inside `enum` which returns you a value depends on case of `QuantumValue`

```
var value: Any {
    switch self {
    case .int(let value):
        return value
    case .string(let value):
        return value
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
...ans_1!.value)!
```

> 1

Also note that type of value is `Any` so if you want to work with it as `String`, you have to downcast it

```
if let string = ...ans_1.value)! as? String {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`QuantumValue` is declared as enum, both *good* cases have associated values.

So printing a value prints both, the case and the associated value.

You could add two properties `intValue` and `stringValue` inside `QuantumValue`

```
var intValue : Int? {
    guard case .int(let num) = self else { return nil }
    return num
}

var stringValue : String? {
    guard case .string(let string) = self else { return nil }
    return string
}
```

Then you can print

```
player1_result_sheet?.ans_1?.intValue
```

---

By the way the name `player1_result_sheet` is pretty *php-ish*.

Please conform to the naming convention.

- Structs, classes and enums are *UpperCamelCased* → `Player1ResultSheet`
- Variables and functions are *lowerCamelCased* → `ans1`

---

And please consolidate your optionals, 6 (six) question and exclamation marks in one line is pretty weird

```
(self.res?.response?.detailData?[indexPath.row].player1_result_sheet?.ans_1!)!
```